# Fedora 25 Cinnamon stuck in graphical login loop, tty login successful

Tags: fedora, permissions, login, cinnamon

I've had a Fedora 25 installation for a day or two in a VM, the Cinnamon spin.

In my last session I ran a few programs, installed Wine, but didn't do a `dnf update`, edit my `.bash_profile`, or make any significant changes that I can recall.

Suddenly, when I attempt to log in, the screen reverts to a cursor on black for about 0.5 seconds (seeming to crash) then the login screen comes back.

**I can log in successfully** as root, using the same UI, so it seems isolated to my user account.

If I `Ctrl+Alt+F5`, I can login successfully, but I see an odd error:

```
Last login: Wed Mar 1 14:02:58 on tty5
 -- craig: /home/craig: change directory failed: Permission denied
Logging in with home = "/".
[craig@localhost /]$ cd
[craig@localhost ~]$ ls -la ~ | grep "\.$"
drwx------. 26 craig craig    4096 Mar  1 13:17 .
drwxr-xr-x. 26 root  root     4096 Feb 28 07:58 ..
[craig@localhost ~]$
```

(Typed the above by hand so excuse any typos.)

I tried changing my home directory permissions to `755` but the result is the same. (Both for graphical and tty login.)

I've done a bit of research, I do not have an `~/.XAuthority` file. I do have `.xsession-errors`, but it doesn't seem to be updated when my login attempts fail. (It's a couple hours old.)

[fpaste link for .xsession-errors](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/Gc3MjFAe12wYfBg2mUPnwl5M1UNdIGYhyRLivL9gydE=/)

I have general working knowledge of Unix, but not a lot of experience with Fedora/Cinnamon. Where should I look next?

Update:

SELinux Alert Browser shows the below options:

[image]

Related AVCs from `ausearch -m AVC` are:

`type=AVC msg=audit(1488394978.226:257): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=1426 comm="login" name="craig" dev="dm-2" ino=2621441 scontext=system_u:system_r:local_login_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0`

Comment: Any AVCs in audit? What about SELinux labels?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check any of that - let me do some research and get back to you, or if you have any one-liners, I'm happy to run them and post the output.

Comment: This seems somewhat promising: http://i.imgur.com/XxmI1PX.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed in the SELinux Alert browser

```
/sbin/restorecon -v /home/craig
```

should resolve the problems.

### What was wrong?

From the AVC:

`type=AVC msg=audit(1488394978.226:257): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=1426 comm="login" name="craig" dev="dm-2" ino=2621441 scontext=system_u:system_r:local_login_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0`

You can read that your home directory (`name="craig"`) had a wrong label (`unlabeled_t`), instead of the expected type (`user_home_dir_t` from the screenshot). SELinux has is MAC (Mandatory Access Control) and the `login` was trying to do something that was not allowed by the policy, it was forbidden.

It was probably caused by some manipulation of your home directory.

Comment: I'll give this a try - but I'm a little confused as to what happened in the first place? I see that `restorecon -v` shows "changes in file labels", but I don't understand exactly what this _does_.

Comment: To find out what happened, you would have to share the whole AVC message that was produced (`ausearch -m AVC` should list all of the AVCs). `restorecon` is fixing the labels to the correct ones if they happened to get wrong (for whatever reason).

Comment: with space ... sorry: `ausearch -m AVC`

Comment: Seems kind of unexciting: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/8eorVt8qQHJNBVdlC1DK9l5M1UNdIGYhyRLivL9gydE= Am I correct in understanding that SELinux killed my login attempt/Cinnamon process because it tried to do something out-of-bounds? SELinux is something I have zero experience with, so you should assume no prior knowledge on my part. :-)

Comment: Yes. See the edited answer with more details.

Comment: Worked great - thanks for explaining the details - a lot to learn since RHEL 4... :-)